# How can I create a Java GUI that reads SQL code and outputs the result?

Tags: java, sql, javafx

I have a Java application successfully connected to a SQL Database. I need to create a simple GUI with 2 dialog boxes, one where I can type in an SQL Query and the 2nd box outputs the result by pulling data from the database after clicking a button. How would I go about doing this code wise? I've set up the GUI, but I don't know how to get the Java to read the SQL queries that I would type in.

Comment: Add a `EventHandler` to the `onAction` property, use a `Button` in a similar vain

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to give an idea how to do.

**Note**: *Assume that the sql is a simple select statement returning few records. And data type of the columns are String.*

```
//inside button click event you can write something like this.
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(/*your connection parameters */); 

String query = textField.getText(); //select * from tableT

String result = "";

PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();  
while(rs.next()){ 
//assume the column types are string and you are trying to get values for two columns 
    result += rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2);      
}
textField2.setText(result);
```

Comment: This answer is going to run into a lot of problem with different queries.

Comment: Yes I'm agree. Usually to show results it is better to use JTable. but according to the solution he need is this. I'l appreciate if you can provide a better way to do it.

Comment: I would find the column count and loop through it inside the while loop. I would also make sure all of my column types are `String` because If you have a column of maybe `int id`, you can't use `rs.getString()` there.

Comment: I am off to bed. I will take a closer look tomorrow if it is not closed by then.

Comment: Yeah, since he had not mentioned the query, column types, it is depends. and this is to get an idea how to do.

Comment: Not to mention that some query's simply do updates... Creating a appropriate `TableView` could be done based on the [`metaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData--)...